# sort comma separated elements

Tags: jquery, sorting, split

I am using this for sorting text in elements:

```
$('div span')
    .sort(function(a, b){
        return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1; 
    })
    .appendTo('div');
```

It works good in cases as

```
<div>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>A</span>
</div>
```

But I need separate them with commas (they are already here before sorting):

```
<div>
    <span>B</span>, <span>C</span>, <span>A</span>
</div>
```

I can't understand where I should use `split` to separate them with commas.
Is it possible without doing everything from scratch? JQuery way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `after` method:

```
$('div span').sort(function (a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo('div').not(':last').after(',');
```

edit: Working with textNodes can make your code unmaintainable, I would suggest wrapping the `,` textNodes with another element, then you can remove them easily without filtering element's textNodes or resetting `innerHTML` of the wrapper element:

```
$('div span.comma').remove();

$('div span').sort(function (a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo('div').not(':last').after('<span class="comma">,</span>');
```

This is one way of filtering textNodes that have `,` as their `nodeValue`:

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) === ','
}).remove();
```

Comment: it works! But I forgot to mention, commas are here before sorting, so they are not removed with `sort`. How do I clear `div` before `appendTo`?